# EF Core Exception Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException not sure why this is being thrown

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I am not sure why the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException is thrown  whilst calling dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync()

Saving to the database includes a few steps.
1. Use Of Automapper to map from viewmodel -> Model. This seems to be working fine
2. Adding the model object to the dbcontext - Seems to work fine.
3.Save the current Dbcontext changes to the database by calling SaveChangesAsync on the dbContext - this throws an exception Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException (the inner exception states 'Invalid object name 'Vehicles')

First off, here is the controller code that does the business. The exception is thrown whilst calling SaveChangesAsync

```
[HttpPost("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostNewVehicleData([FromBody]VehicleViewModel vehicleData_)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newVehicle = _mapper.Map<Vehicle>(vehicleData_);
            _vehicleRepository.AddVehicle(newVehicle);
            if (await _vehicleRepository.SaveChangesAsync())
            {
                return Created($"api/Vehicles/{vehicleData_.Notes}", _mapper.Map<VehicleViewModel>(newVehicle)); 
            }
        } 

        return BadRequest("Failed to save the vehicle");
```

As previously stated, the inner exception states 'Invalid Object Name Vehicles'. There is a 'Vehicles' property in the class instance i am trying to save. This 'Vehicles' property exists so a one to many (one dealer many vehicles) relationship can be set up in the underlying database. Does anyone have any ideas as to why EF core is 'complaining' about this property??

```
public class Dealer
{
    public Dealer()
    {

    }
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string DealerName {get; set;}
    public string StreetAddress{get; set;}
    public City City{get;set;}
    public string PostalCode{get;set;}
    public string WebAddress{get;set;}
    public string PhoneNumber{get;set;}
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles{get;set;}
    public int CityForeignKey{get; set;}

}
```

the

Comment: What's the name of the `Vehicles` table in database?

Comment: This is a SQL Server error. It means there's no `Vehicles` table in the database.

Comment: Just checked the Db - yes, it is true that there is no 'Vehicles' table. It is named 'Vehicle' - will change code accordingly and see what happens.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and @p e p  - solved. I simply renamed the Vehicles property to Vehicles, created an EF core migration folowed by a db update and this works just fine. I am now able to save to the database.

Comment: Hello, @PanagiotisKanavos Have received the same error in the production environment, I am not able to find out what actually wrong as it is working and in-between there is this error at _context.SaveChangesAsync(); line. I am creating a smslog entry in the database. Exception :- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException     error :- String or binary data would be truncated.  The statement has been terminated.